# How to remove or replace substring in Python determined by start and end point?

Tags: python, regex, string

From time to time I would remove or replace substring of one long string. Therefore, I would determine one start patern and one end patern which would determine start and end point of substring:

```
long_string = "lorem ipsum..white chevy..blah,blah...lot of text..beer bottle....and so to the end"
removed_substr_start = "white chevy"
removed_substr_end = "beer bott"

# this is pseudo method down
STRresult = long_string.replace( [from]removed_substr_start [to]removed_substr_end, "")
```

Comment: Have you looked into using a regular expression?

Comment: Long time ago, but didn't remember some method of start - end pointing.

Comment: I think you're too focussed on calculating the start and end points and not on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, but it appears to be useful, and I'm wondering should I build my own function if there's no built in.

Comment: There is, and it's a regular expression, see my answer. (edit: and now all the other answers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you want something like that, without regex:

```
def replace_between(text, begin, end, alternative=''):
    middle = text.split(begin, 1)[1].split(end, 1)[0]
    return text.replace(middle, alternative)
```

Not tested and you should protected the first line from exception (if begin or end is not found), but the idea is here :)

Comment: Hey, guys....all +1. But this one is without re importing. Thanks a lot for such lection about strings.

Comment: There's lots of ways to do this. I'm not saying that one method is better than another. But you should be clear what you are trying to achieve and open minded in accepting an answer. This solution involves writing extra code when the function already exists in regular expressions. What's wrong with importing a module? It's the way Python is designed to work.

Comment: For example of why not to write code when it already exists, here is a bug. Try a string where the end string comes before the start string. It will remove a portion of the string. Not what you expected.

Comment: If the input is `"lorem ipsum..beer bottle..blah,blah...lot of text..white chevy....and so to the end"`, the output is `"lorem ipsum..beer bottle..blah,blah...lot of text..white chevy"`. Where did the end go?

Comment: Alright, my method isn't perfect, but it's an alternative of regex. I'm sure it's possible to make a better function with `find` and `rfind` ;)

Comment: Cool. Sorry to pick holes, but anyone could come along and copy-paste this and introduce bugs into their own code. You never know!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = "lorem ipsum..white chevy..blah,blah...lot of text..beer bottle....and so to the end"
>>> sub_start = "white chevy"
>>> sub_end = "beer bott"
>>> re.sub(r'{}.*?{}'.format(re.escape(sub_start),re.escape(sub_end)),'',strs)
'lorem ipsum..le....and so to the end'
```

If you only want to remove the sub-string between `"white chevy"` and `"beer bott"` but not these words:

```
>>> re.sub(r'({})(.*?)({})'.format(re.escape(sub_start),
                                               re.escape(sub_end)),r'\1\3',strs)
'lorem ipsum..white chevybeer bottle....and so to the end'
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the starting index using `string.find()` and the last index using `string.rfind()` and then just remove the inner part using:

```
lindex = string.find(long_string, removed_substr_start)
rindex = string.find(long_string, removed_substr_end, lindex)
result = long_string[0:lindex] + longstring[rindex:]
```

See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find

Comment: That should be considered too.

Comment: Use `str`'s methods, `string` module is not used for these methods any more. And this [won't work in py3.x](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions).

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
regexp = "white chevy.*?beer bott"
long_string = "lorem ipsum..white chevy..blah,blah...lot of text..beer bottle....and so to the end"
re.sub(regexp, "", long_string)
```

gives:

```
'lorem ipsum..le....and so to the end'
```

Answer (score 1):

After use of many approaches, I found this solution the best without regex:

```
def getString( str, _from, _to ):
    end_from = str.find( _from ) +len( _from)
    return str[ end_from : str.find( _to, end_from ) ]
```