# Find expression delimited by known strings

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am looking to make a list of the elements comprised between the expressions "cat_" and " dog"
in a string that looks like:

```
input=...snake_perrot_cat_expression dog...
output='expression'
```

I want for 'expression' to be returned. I attempted to use regex, but I lack the experience to know how to write it properly...

```
identifi=[]
for line in file:
    identi=re.findall(r'cat_.*?dog', line)
    identifi.append(identi)
```

It returns an empty list... Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920366/how-to-remove-or-replace-substring-in-python-determined-by-start-and-end-point

Comment: Note that you initialize a list called `identifi`, but you append to something called `indentifi`. Could that be the problem? (Too many similar variable names is a programming pitfall...)

Comment: @unutbu Sorry this was not present in the original version... simply a typo when I wrote it down here.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, I do not know how that question escaped me while I was looking through SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put parentheses around the pattern you want to find:

```
    indentifi.extend(re.findall(r'cat_(.*?)dog', line))
```

---

For example,

```
In [137]: import re

In [138]: line = '...snake_perrot_cat_expression dog...'

In [142]: re.findall(r'cat_(.*?)\s*dog', line)
Out[142]: ['expression']
```

(The `\s*` was added so trailing whitespace won't be matched.)

Comment: You are my hero... thanks, I have learned something new about re thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a solution without using regular expression, if you have only one "cat" and "dog" in each line, and "cat" comes first:

```
print inpu.split('cat_')[1].split('dog')[0]
```